# Parsing Json Response from api call - foreach error

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am working with the instagram api. This question is not `Instagram` specific but more about parsing the response returned by the api call. The api works with pagination. With some research I found the way to fetch all the results in one huge bulk and avoid pagination. I am having an issue parsing the json file. In the `foreach` loop I attempt the parse but I get this error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. How could I parse the json file values properly in the `foreach` loop?

[LINK](http://techchurian.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/displaying-all-your-instagram-images-ignoring-next-page-and-pagination/) to article that explains the process if not familiar with api

**Issue Here**: Trying to parse in `foreach loop` - Included a test access token. This can be tested from anywhere

```
$get_media_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nataliguatemipoa/media/recent?access_token=6678174.467ede5.205a03ebc4b74d4082823781c3149575';

$media = getResults($get_media_url); //Look Below to find function details
foreach($media['data'] as $insta){
        $source_id = $insta['id'];
    }
```

Here’s an example of an Instagram response,

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pagination] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [next_min_id] => 1407287255810188
                    [deprecation_warning] => next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead
                    [min_tag_id] => 1407287255810188
                )

            [meta] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [code] => 200
                )

            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [attribution] => 
                            [tags] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => muff
                                    [1] => hairstylist
                                )
//Cut the rest for example purposes
```

*Make the api call*

```
function __apiCall($url, $post_parameters = FALSE) {

        // Initialize the cURL session
        $curl_session = curl_init();

        // Set the URL of api call
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        // If there are post fields add them to the call
        if($post_parameters !== FALSE) {
            curl_setopt ($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_parameters);
        }

        // Return the curl results to a variable
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // Execute the cURL session
        $contents = curl_exec ($curl_session);

        // Close cURL session
        curl_close ($curl_session);

        // Return the response
        return  json_decode($contents);
    }
```

*Fetch all pagination results*

```
function getResults($url){

        $gotAllResults = false;
        $results = array();

        while(!$gotAllResults) {
        $result = $this-&gt;__apiCall($url);
        $results[] = $result;

        if (!property_exists($result-&gt;pagination, 'next_url')) {
            $gotAllResults = true;
        } else {
            $url = $result-&gt;pagination-&gt;next_url;
        }
    }

    return $results;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$insta` is an object, not an array. You should be referencing as such:

```
foreach($media[data] as $insta){
    $source_id = $insta->id;
}
```

---

<sup>*Objects are referenced as `->`. Arrays are referenced as `[]`*</sup>

One of two options here, you could try referencing it as this first one:

```
foreach($media['data'] as $insta){
    $source_id = $insta->id;
}
```

Or you could try as an object

```
foreach($media->data as $insta){
    $source_id = $insta->id;
}
```

Comment: Ok it is still giving the same error of  `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: What does `print_r($media)` supply?

Comment: But is `data` present in there?

Comment: Yes `data` is present

Comment: Showing that `print_r($media)` would be great so we can help you debug

Comment: `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["pagination"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (3) { ["next_min_id"]=> string(16) "1407287255810188" ["deprecation_warning"]=> string(94) "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead" ["min_tag_id"]=> string(16) "1407287255810188" } ["meta"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["code"]=> int(200) } ["data"]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (15)`

Comment: Try `$media[0]->data` or `foreach($media as $item) {foreach($item['data'] as $insta){.....}}`

Comment: Hmm not sure what deal is but I keep getting `Cannot use object of type stdClass`

Answer (score 0):

Try with casting it to `array` -

```
foreach((array)$media[0]['data'] as $insta) {
   $source_id = $insta->id;
}
```

Comment: Ok so the error goes away but no values are placed in the foreach loop. It gives this error `Notice: Undefined index: data in /index.php on line 226`

Comment: `var_dump($media)` and add see what you are getting or display it.

Comment: `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["pagination"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (3) { ["next_min_id"]=> string(16) "1407287255810188" ["deprecation_warning"]=> string(94) "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead" ["min_tag_id"]=> string(16) "1407287255810188" } ["meta"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["code"]=> int(200) } ["data"]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (15) `

Comment: It yield this error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: it was coming because the `$insta` is an object.if `$insta` has `id` in next level then you can access it else again loop must be added.updated the answer.

Comment: No luck with that either.

Comment: can you display the full object you are getting properly with the question?

Comment: Edited my question with the complete code so you can test.